# JS value to PHP variable to change div background color with PHP If else statement

Tags: php

I have the below div where i use a PHP if else to change the background color of the div based on the $tteg value which is equal to a JS value called {{ reviewsOverall }} , i don't know if i did equal them correctly but it seems to work, the problem i am facing is the color of the background is always red, i am not sure if the below code is correct, please help.

What i want to do is IF {{ reviewsOverall }} value is below 7 div background-color to be red, else to be green, i want to mention that {{ reviewsOverall }} value starts from 0 till 10 and when its for example 5 its without decimals but if its 3.1 or others its with one decimal after the point. I am adding the below code in Wordpress Plugin editor, thanks in advance for your help, much appreciated.

```
<div
 
class="rwp-users-score <?php if ( $is_UR ) echo 'rwp-ur' ?>"
 
<?php $tteg = "{{ reviewsOverall }}"; ?>
 
 <?php if ($tteg < 7): ?>

style='background-color: red;'

<?php elseif ($tteg >= 7): ?>

style='background-color: green;'

<?php else: ?>

style='background-color: black;'

<?php endif ?> >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP can't read JavaScript variables - that's because they are simply not available at the point that PHP is run.

So, in this case, you are better staying with pure JavaScript to accomplish what is really a UI challenge - it will also make your code cleaner and better organised.

Here is a basic ( untested ) solution:

```
<script>
    $( function() {
       
       color = 'red'; // default ##
       if ( '7' >= reviewsOverall ){
        
           color = 'blue';
           
       } elseif ( '7' < reviewsOverall ){
        
           color = 'pink';
           
       }

       $('.rwp-users-score').css('background-color', color );

    });
</script>
```

This script could be added inline on the template or added to a scripts.js file and included using `wp_enqueue_script()` - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: can i add this in the wordpress plugin editor php file? switch won't do it for me, i need if else statement for ranges from [0;7) and [7;10]

Comment: What is the "wordpress plugin editor php file" ? you can make also switch statements work, they accept operators.

Comment: What is the "wordpress plugin editor php file" ?  - its where you edit your plugin files in Wordpress, you don't know? :)

Comment: Right, but, no - that's really the wrong place to be looking - if the plugin is your own, edit it in a IDE and track your changes - if it is not your plugin - don't edit it --- WP should really remove that feature as it goes against everything WP is trying to achieve.

Comment: Its a plugin with license, don't worry.

Comment: That's not the point - it's just a bad way to edit code - no debugging, no backup, no help from the editor etc.. and, if your code changes cause a fatal error - no WP plugin editor to fix that problem you just caused.. my advice is to get used to working with code in a way that will help you and is more secure.

Comment: Yes, i agree with you. The plugin author is not so helpful and super slow in replies so... yeah :)

Comment: Thanks Q Studio, your answer is my solution, thank you so much.